# List shared files OneDrive for business

Tags: python, onedrive

I'm looking to list files that have been shared with me on OneDrive for business with the Python OneDrive SDK (onedrive-python-sdk)

I've successfully authenticated and been able to list files I have using the following code

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
client_id = your_client_id
client_secret = your_client_secret
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                                client_id,
                                auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=discovery_uri)
# If you have access to more than one service, you'll need to decide
# which ServiceInfo to use instead of just using the first one, as below.
service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
auth.redeem_refresh_token(service_info.service_resource_id)
client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(service_info.service_resource_id + '/_api/v2.0/', auth, http)

#get the top three elements of root, leaving the next page for more elements
collection = client.item(drive='me', id='root').children.request(top=3).get()
# print files
print collection
```

However I'm not sure how to request the **files that have been shared with me**, I've seen references in the OneDrive API to use the following  request, but I'm not sure how to make the call

```
GET /drive/view.sharedWithMe
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll prefix this answer with a disclaimer that I don't have an environment set up to validate this python solution, but I believe it should work (or worst case provide you with an idea to solve it).

You're correct in that the current SDK does not expose the `view.sharedWithMe`, however it thankfully contains the tools you need to do it yourself. You'll want to use the `append_to_request_url` function in conjunction with the `ItemsCollectionRequestBuilder` like so:

```
collection = ItemsCollectionRequestBuilder(client.drive.append_to_request_url("view.sharedWithMe"), client).request(top=3).get()
```

Hopefully this will give you the results that you're after.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, this worked an absolute treat!

Comment: @user29184827194701 Where you able to download the file later on ?